# Indexing the Graph

Tags: r

```
   x = rnorm( 50, 0.5)
   y = rnorm(50, 0, 1) 
   plot(x, type='l',col="red")
   lines(y, col="green")
```

I have to create an Index in the graph explaining red represents object x and green is for y 
Just like in MS Excel you can create a small index in the graph

Answer (score 0):

When you say "index", do you mean legend? If so, then you can use the `legend` function:

```
legend("topleft", col=2:3, legend=c("x", "y"), lty=1)
```

Look at the associated help file - `?legend` - for further information.